# What features does the Microsoft Graph API share with the legacy Partner CREST API

Tags: rest, api, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-commerce-server

Wanting to know features does the Microsoft Graph API share with the legacy Azure [CREST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/mt634708.aspx). I believe the Microsoft Graph API vision is to have this support, as it is aimed to be a unified API for all Microsoft content. On that note as well, what other alternatives are there to the CREST API for partners?

For some context on what CREST provides, see this quote from [Partner Center REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/mt667943.aspx).

> The Partner Center REST API helps Cloud Solution Provider partners
>   integrate their existing **CRM** or **billing software** with the Microsoft
>   systems that manage customer accounts, place orders, manage
>   subscriptions, and handle support requests.

Answer (score 0):

At present, the Microsoft Graph doesn't support Partner Center REST API. You can refer the figure below about the detail support for [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs):

[image]

If you want the Microsoft Graph to integrate the Partner Center REST API, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Image link is broken.